# Schechter' luminosity function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, astronomy, luminosity

I need your help.

I need show that the Schechter' Luminosity Function with: $\alpha = -1.5$ the limited-magnitude of a survey will be detected from a sample of galaxies with this characteristics: only $\sim 5 \%$ of galaxies will have $L < 0.05 l^*$, $\sim 50 \%$ will have $L > 0.7 L^*$ and only $\sim 5 \%$ will have $L > 3L^*$.

Comment: More information needed: what is the magnitude limit of the survey? What cosmology are you assuming? If you're using a realistic expanding universe cosmology, what spectrum do the galaxies have? And how do the Schechter parameters (spectra included) evolve with time? Most likely, you're assuming a static cosmology, where redshifts and their complications can be ignored, but that needs clarification.

Comment: I do not have more information about the problem. I guess that is using the the Schechter' function but changing  L by M, (Magnitude). Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I don't think that's what's happening here. Magnitude limits of surveys are usually flux limits, not absolute magnitude limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that you're dealing with a static cosmology and static luminosity function. Then, from the definition of the luminosity function, the number of galaxies with luminosity $\ell$ greater than a minimum luminosity $L$ and closer than a maximum distance $R$ is given by:
$$N(r < R, \ell > L) = \int_0^R \operatorname{d}r \int_L^\infty \operatorname{d} \ell\, \Omega_s r^2 \Phi(\ell),$$
where $\Omega_s$ is the solid angle subtended by the survey.

Changing out the radius limit for a flux limit using $F = \frac{L}{4\pi r^2}$ $\left(\mathrm{thus\ } \frac{\operatorname{d} r}{\operatorname{d} F} = -\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{L}{4\pi F^3}}\right)$ gives:
\begin{align}N(f > F, \ell > L) &= \Omega_s\int_F^\infty \operatorname{d}f \int_L^\infty \operatorname{d}\ell\, \frac{\sqrt{\ell}}{16\pi^{3/2} f^{3/2}}\left(\frac{\ell}{f}\right) \Phi(\ell)\\
& = \frac{\Omega_s}{16\pi^{3/2}} \int_F^\infty \operatorname{d}f\, f^{-5/2} \int_L^\infty \operatorname{d}\ell\, \ell^{3/2} \Phi(\ell) \\
&= \frac{\Omega_s}{16\pi^{3/2} F^{3/2}} \int_L^\infty \operatorname{d}\ell\, \ell^{3/2} \Phi(\ell).
\end{align}
Dropping in the Schechter function, $\Phi(L) = \phi_\star L^\alpha L_\star^{-\alpha} \operatorname{e}^{-L/L_\star}$, gives:
$$N(f > F, \ell > L) = \frac{\Omega_s \phi_\star L_\star}{24\pi^{3/2}F^{3/2}} \Gamma\left(\alpha+\frac{5}{2},\, \frac{L}{L_\star}\right),$$
where $\Gamma(a,x)$ is the (upper) [incomplete gamma function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.2); be careful what software library you use to compute this - some define the incomplete gamma function such that it is normalized. In this case, however, you can use $L\rightarrow 0$, which gives the ordinary gamma function. The rest is calculating ratios of $N$ with different values of $L$, which will make the results independent of $F$, $\alpha$, and $\phi_\star$:
$$\frac{N(\ell > L_1)}{N(\ell > L_2)}  = \frac{\Gamma\left(\alpha+\frac{5}{2},\, \frac{L_1}{L_\star}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\alpha+\frac{5}{2},\, \frac{L_2}{L_\star}\right)}.$$

With $\alpha=-1.5$ the integral can be evaluated explicitly to get $\Gamma(-1.5 + 5/2, x) = (1+x) \operatorname{e}^{-x}$. Plug in the appropriate limits (and maybe do a little more algebra for the part with an upper limit).

Comment: Your anwser is very elegant, however, my problem shoud be very simple but I do not understand it. Check http://www.as.utexas.edu/~sj/a358-sp12/hwk1.pdf